# MySQL: Strange AUTO_INCREMENT

Tags: mysql

Table looks like:

```
mysql> DESC text;
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| Field           | Type         | Null | Key | Default           | Extra          |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment |
| text            | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL              |                |
+-----------------+--------------+------+-----+-------------------+----------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

and **AUTO_INCREMENT** is 1:

```
mysql> ALTER TABLE text AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.36 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0
```

but I get strange id like:

```
mysql> SELECT id FROM text;
+------------+
| id         |
+------------+
| 2147483647 |
+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What is the problem?

Comment: truncate the table once and then check the id on inserting the new row.

Comment: Why would I truncate it? I've already reset AUTO_INCREMENT before testing.

Comment: You resetted the default value for the **next** insert. But the current data does not change of course

Comment: "I'VE ALREADY RESET AUTO_INCREMENT  ______BEFORE______ TESTING"

Comment: What does your insert query look like?

Answer (score 2):

When you change the auto increment it is set to `greatest(your_value,max(column)+ 1)`

though I cant find the part in the docs which mention it, it is in the comments

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

```
ALTER TABLE text AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

then check the result of

```
SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT`
FROM  INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DatabaseName'
AND   TABLE_NAME   = 'text';
```

to confirm that its not actually 1